# dd over smb to reformat ntfs as ext3

Tags: dd, smb

I've been told it's possible to use `dd` to reformat a portion of a Windows share drive from NTFS to ext3.  I'd like to do this to be able to preserve permissions when using rsync for backups, but I cannot get it to work.

I'm trying, from Unbuntu 12.04 and from Mac OS X.8.5, variants of

```
dd if=/dev/zero of="smb://WIN;username@IPaddress/path.ext3" bs=1024 count=1048576
```

All of the variants of quotation mark presence/absence, single/double, and position I've tried all result in

```
dd: smb://WIN: No such file or directory
```

Smb to the remote directory works fine.

Comment: The idea here, apparently, is to create an ext3 filesystem in a file stored on NTFS filesystem, mount that, and then use `rsync`?